# If cell address = cell address Then

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I'm having an issue working out how to get my if statement to check if cell  address's match instead of the value.

```
'Top
Dim cellT As String
Dim columnT As Integer
 Dim rowT As Integer

'Bottom
Dim cellB As String
Dim columnB As Integer
Dim rowB As Integer

If cellT = cellB Then
    Range("A1").Select

Else

    More code

End If
```

The cells are normally the same cell but if a new line is inserted I want the next section "more code" to be run.

Comment: Can you provide more detail?  You have empty strings assigned to both `cellB` and `cellT`, so `if "" = "" then` will always evaluate to `True`.  Show how and where these strings are assigned, and if possible to describe the actual problem -- if there is an error, what is it? If the results are not what you expect, then describe the situation and your expectations, etc.

Comment: your code makes little or no sense as it stands, you are looking to get the cell address I take it? `sheet1.Cells(1,1).Address` will give you the address.

Comment: My crystal ball may need cleaning but it looks like `If rowT = rowB And columnT = columnB Then` should work just as easily as `If Cells(rowT, columnT).Address = Cells(rowB, columnB).Address Then`.

Comment: To @Jeeped's point,  the key here is that in order to identify a cell in the first place, one needs to provide a row & column. ie: if you are going to set CellA = Range("A1"), you have already told CellA what it's column and row are. So instead of checking CellA against CellB, just seperately store your row and column when you assign it, and compare those values directly.

Comment: @DavidZemens apologies I was trying to clear down the just the bit I was having an issue with to make it clearer which obviously i failed at.

Comment: @Jeeped thanks your comment gave me the hint I needed, what i was after was.

`If (Range(cellT).Address = Range(cellB).Address) Then`

I'd already used the Integers to make the cell string I just forgot to remove them when i was clearing down the code which probably confused people.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the wrong syntax i needed to define the string as a Range and that it was the Address not a Value.

```
If (Range(cellT).Address = Range(cellB).Address) Then
```

Comment: Why go through the overhead of Range().Address, when simple equivalence of `If cellT = cellB Then` should work? Otherwise, you're taking two strings (which you could test for equivalence), feeding them in to a Range object (as the address), and then extracting the `.Address` from the range object to check for equivalence. Do you see the redundancy in that?